# How can I fix a blank space at top, bottom, right and left outside desktop screen?

Tags: nvidia, display, display-resolution, 18.04, external-monitor

I just upgraded from 16.04. When the LiveCD was running it showed the desktop screen that filled the entire monitor screen. After my installation of 18.04 there is black empty space at the top, bottom, left and right of the screen outside of the desktop screen. I searched the forum and didn't find a solution. I tried changing the resolution with terminal commands using this tutorial without success at http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop

In The terminal, I typed xrandr and it says:

DVI-D-1 connected primary 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm

I tried setting the NVIDIA graphics driver to one that is proprietary, tested but nothing has changed.

My monitor is an old samsung SyncMaster 220wm. Is there something I can do to fix this problem or do I need to replace the monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed the problem. All I did was to first run some updates and then in the Software Updater I went to the tab under Additional Drivers and selected the proprietary NVIDIA driver, apply changes. Waited until the changes were installed, closed window and then restarted the computer.